# How do I get this separated mesh to function properly with the included animation?

Tags: armature, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I have this figure:

[image]

His right arm is included as a separate mesh.  The armature is designed for this arm to function together with the rest of the mesh in an animation, but the arm has come detached from the armature:

[image]

[image]

If I select the armature and go into edit mode, the armature reverts to a default pose, in which it lines up perfectly with the detached arm:

[image]

I have tried parenting the detached arm to the armature.  Under Armature Deform, the three options I have are:

- With Empty Groups.  This doesn't work because I don't know which vertices in the detached arm should be assigned to which vertex groups.
- With Automatic Weights. I get the error "Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones"
- With Envelope Weights.  This succeeds insofar as it aligns the mesh with the bones in the armature, but it also distorts the mesh badly:

[image]

How can I get this mesh to work properly with the armature?

Answer (score 0):

Name correctly the bones of your armature (the left arm bone needs to be called *arm_L*), join the arms to the rest of the body, parent the mesh to the armature *With Empty Groups*, select the arm vertices, go into the *Vertex Groups* list, select the vertex group called *arm_L*, click on *Assign*.

If you want to leave the arm as a separate object, select the arm, shift select the armature, switch to *Pose* mode, select the arm bone then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Bone*.

Comment: The problem with that is that the arm part of the armature is made up of many little bones, all of which have a role in the animation.  I'd need to part out the arm's mesh into vertex groups, and I don't know which vertices should belong to which groups.